# accessing Centos SAMBA shares from windows server 2019

Tags: centos, windows, samba

I'm a very basic Unix user and just trying to teach myself stuff..
I have a few samba shares from a Centos unix machine.
These shares can be accessed fine from standing alone windows 10 machines but I cannot access the Centos box from the explorer window itself from my windows server 2019 system.
Its not that I cannot access the shares within, but its the actual computer I cannot access.  Saying Windows cannot access \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx check the path etc.

Usually I would assume that its block ports but I have checked ports 139 and 445 via telnet and have no issues with those paths.

Looking for some ideas.  Cheers.

here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    disable netbios = yes
    server min protocol = NT1
    server max protocol = SMB3
    map to guest = bad user

[data]
    comment = DataTestFolder
    path = /data
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Sounds like a Windows routing problem. Can Windows `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`? Not yet a Linux/Samba problem, but a networking problem.

Comment: yep, it can ping.  there is a nodejs webserver running on that unix system also, which is fully accessable also

Comment: 'disable netbios = yes' means do not use SMBv1, but 'server min protocol = NT1' means use SMBv1. Which do you want to use ?

Comment: yeah, i was experimenting with multiple different things.  i did have that line commented out in previous tests.  I'm not sure if having both those settings conflict.. but I did change it after you pointed it out